# Laravel at least one field is required

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have two field `billable_option` and `billable_option_yes`. I want to validate at least one field is mandatory. I have tried:

```
$this->validate($request,[
    'billable_option'=>'required'|'billable_option_yes'=>'required',
]);
```

I want to check at least one field is required in `Laravel-5.3`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can try with the [required_without](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-required-without).

```
$rules = array(
   'billable_option' => 'required_without:billable_option_yes',
   'billable_option_yes' => 'required_without:billable_option'
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try checking out [required_without_all:foo,bar,...,](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-required-without-all) it looks like that should do it for you. To quote their documentation:

The field under validation must be present only when the all of the other specified fields are not present.

**Example:**

```
$rules = array(
   'billable_option' => 'required_without_all:billable_option_yes',
   'billable_option_yes' => 'required_without_all:billable_option'
);
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
```

Hope this helps you!