# How can validate and show atleast one dropdown required using laravel validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have a form that form has two dropdown. If I submit form I need to validate and show at-least one dropdown required. I have added some functionality but not working.

**create.blade.php**

```
<select class="form-control" id="user" name="user">
     <option value="0"> select user </option>
     <option value="1"> jane </option>
     <option value="2"> peter </option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" id="email" name="email">
     <option value="0"> select email</option>
     <option value="1"> jane@gmail.com </option>
     <option value="2"> peter@gmail.com </option>
</select>
```

**CreateRequest.php**

```
public function rules()
{
   $rules = [
             'user' => 'required_without_all:email|not_in:0',
             'email' => 'required_without_all:user|not_in:0',
            ];
   return $rules;
}
```

Comment: See my answer in this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46909982/laravel-at-least-one-field-is-required/46910085#46910085   Hope it helps!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel at least one field is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46909982/laravel-at-least-one-field-is-required)

Comment: @RaunakGupta Yes, i think. So that i posted same link here and told to check my answer. If it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `required_without_all` use `required_without`. The former accepts a list of fields, whereas you only need one.

Also, skip using value '0' for your `select` placeholder, and then remove that from your validation.

For example:

```
    <select class="form-control" id="user" name="user" placeholder="Select user">
         <option value=""> select user </option>
         <option value="1"> jane </option>
         <option value="2"> peter </option>
    </select>
```

and the validation:

```
'user' => 'required_without:email',
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Use `required_without` this will solve your problem.

```
$rules = [
    'user' => 'required_without:email|not_in:0',
    'email' => 'required_without:user|not_in:0',
];
```

*Hope this helps!*